# nodejs How can I create multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array

How can I create a multidimensional array in nodejs? And push data in it?

How can I get an old-fashioned array inside an array, like this:

```
array{ sub_array1[(key1, value1)(key2,value2)],sub_array2[(key1, value1)(key2,value2)]}
```

So far I have tried lots of combinations of:

```
array.push()
```

---

okie., as per answered by **rsp** .,
i have managed to get it like this

```
out_array.push( {   'key1' :value1,
                    'key2' : value2 ,
                    'key3': value3,
                    'key4': value4,
                    'key5': value5
                } );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no multidimensional arrays in JavaScript in the strict sense, but you can create an array that has other arrays as elements. The same with objects - I add it because it seems that what you want is objects and not arrays, or maybe a mixed structure with objects and arrays.

```
let arrayOfArrays = [[1, 2, 3], ['x', 'y', 'z']];
let objectOfObjects = { a: { x: 1, y: 2 }, b: { x: 3, y: 4 } };
let arrayOfObjects = [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }];
let objectOfArrays = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: ['x', 'y', 'z'] };
```

You access elements like this:

```
arrayOfArrays[1][2] === 'z';
objectOfObjects.b.x === 3;
arrayOfObjects[1].y === 4;
objectOfArrays.a[2] === 3;
```

Note that `objectOfObjects.b.x` is the same as `objectOfObjects['b']['x']` but shorter. Usually you use the bracket syntax when you have the key name in a variable, like this:

```
let key1 = 'b';
let key2 = 'x';
objectOfObjects[key1][key2] === objectOfObjects.b.x;
```

Comment: so there is no key=>value pair ?

Comment: @AMB no, `key => value` pairs are in Perl - see: [perldoc perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html). In JavaScript the pairs are `key: value` as in `{ x: 1, y: 2 }` in the example in my answer. The `=>` in JavaScript is a so called "fat arrow" which is an operator to create arrow functions, see [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my small examle:

```
let obj = {
    foo: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
};

Object.assign(obj, {
    bar: true
});
console.log(obj);

obj.foo.push(7);
console.log(obj);

for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(key + '=' + obj[key]);
}
```